# Insert a column then put a formula in the blank column 500 times

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code that I am using

```
Sub insert_column_every_other()
Dim colx As Long
Dim H As Worksheet
Set H = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Replace H3 with the sheet that contains your data
For colx = 9 To 1200 Step 2
    Call H.Columns(colx).Insert(Shift:=xlToRight)
    H.Range(H.Cells(2, colx), H.Cells(21, colx)).FormulaR1C1 = "= 
((OFFSET(RC[-1])-(OFFSET(RC[-3]))/(OFFSET(RC[-3]))*SQRT(252))"
Next colx
End Sub
```

Getting an error in the following line,

```
H.Range(H.Cells(2, colx), H.Cells(21, colx)).FormulaR1C1 = "= 
((OFFSET(RC[-1])-(OFFSET(RC[-3]))/(OFFSET(RC[-3]))*SQRT(252))"
```

The error is Application-defined error.

The macro will create a column after the 9th column till the 500th column and then in the blank column will calculate the percentage difference of the stock price of two consecutive days so that's why I went with that particular offset formula.

Comment: Just want to make sure i'm not interpreting the equation wrong, what equation would show in cell H10 after the macro is complete?

Comment: =((G10-F10)/F10)*SQRT(252)

Comment: Absolute ("`A1C1`") cell references would likely prevent the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
Option Explicit

Sub insert_column_every_other()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For i = 9 To 1200 Step 2
        ws.Columns(i).Insert
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(21, i)).Formula = "=(" & ws.Cells(2, i - 1).Address(False, False) & "-" & ws.Cells(2, i - 2).Address(False, False) & ")/(" & ws.Cells(2, i - 2).Address(False, False) & ")*SQRT(252)"
    Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What’s the verdict? I don’t want to leave a solution here if it doesn’t work so I don’t deter other potential answers

Comment: This works. Just need to do a minor adjustment to the formula.  Thank you! Mind telling me what additions you made and why?

Comment: I just didn’t use R1C1 formula style since I find them confusing

Comment: Just realized I changed some names. I just used naming conventions that are more standard/familiar to me. ws = H and i = colx. I also toggled off screen updating and auto calculation to boost run time. The only important change is switching R1C1 for standard formula which is just more intuitive for me (reasons I asked you to clarify the formula in comment as they don’t click with me for some reason)